# Java Plugins With A Custom Interface

Tags: java, class, plugins, jar, loader

Like spigot/bukkit plugins id like to be able to load jars in a file and load their classes. Ive managed to get this working with java class loader but the class has to extend a runnable for it to work. Id like to have my own custom interface to implement for each plugin(jar). So I could have functions that get ran on plugin load and so on. If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Plugin structure

A plugin is a `.jar` file. The plugin has a plugin.properties file with the properties of the plugin.

It looks like this:

```
plugin.main=com.example.plugins.ExamplePlugin
plugin.name=Example Plugin
plugin.description=Test 123
plugin.version=1.0
```

The file contains the main class, the plugin name, a description and the version.

A plugin must have a class that inherits from the abstract plugin class. This counts as the main class.

### Code structure

Let's begin with the `Plugin`-class:

```
package com.example.plugins;

public abstract class Plugin {
    
    protected PluginProperty property;
    
    public abstract void onEnable();
    public abstract void onDisable();

    public PluginProperty getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
    public void setProperty(PluginProperty property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

As you may see, I have chosen an **abstract** class here.

The class consists of two abstract methods (`onEnable` and `onDisable`). The plugin also has a `PluginProperty` object. The equivalent of this class in *Spigot* would be `JavaPlugin`.

Let's take a look at the `PluginProperty` class.

```
package com.example.plugins;

public class PluginProperty {
    
    private String main;
    
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double version;
    
    public PluginProperty(String main, String name, String description, double version) {
        this.main = main;
        
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(double version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

This class has all the necessary properties of a plugin in it. Most of the things here are self-explanatory, but I would still like to discuss `main`.

The string holds the name of the main plugin class of the plugin. This is basically the same as the `main` in the **plugin.yml** in *Spigot*.

### The loader

Here is the `PluginLoader`-class:

```
package com.example.plugins;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;

public class PluginLoader {
    
    private static PluginProperty loadPluginProperties(File file) throws ZipException, IOException {
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        String jarURL = "jar:" + url +"!/plugin.properties";
        
        InputStream input;
        URL inputURL = new URL(jarURL);
        JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection)inputURL.openConnection();
        input = conn.getInputStream();
        
        Properties property = new Properties();
        
        property.load(input);
        
        String main = property.getProperty("plugin.main");
        
        String name = property.getProperty("plugin.name");
        String description = property.getProperty("description");
        double version = Double.parseDouble(property.getProperty("plugin.version"));
        
        
        return new PluginProperty(main, name, description, version);
    }
    
    public static Plugin loadPlugin(File file) throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        if(!file.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        PluginProperty property = loadPluginProperties(file);
        
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        String jarURL = "jar:" + url + "!/";
        URL urls[] = {new URL(jarURL)};
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Plugin plugin = (Plugin) Class.forName(property.getMain(), true, ucl).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        plugin.setProperty(property);
        
        return plugin;
    }
}
```

The private `loadPluginProperties` method loads the plugin properties and returns the required object. The `loadPlugin` method loads the main class specified in the properties into an object and returns it.

### Examples

I just gave you the basic framework for the plugin system. But how should you use it? Let's start with an example loader.

Here is the `Main`-class:

```
package com.example.plugins;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static List<Plugin> plugins = new ArrayList<Plugin>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] pluginFiles = new File("plugins").listFiles();
        
        //Load plugins
        for(File f : pluginFiles) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            if(!f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                continue;
            }
            
            Plugin p = null;
            
            try {
                p = PluginLoader.loadPlugin(f);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Failed to load plugin!");
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            Main.plugins.add(p);
        }
        
        //Enable plugins
        for(Plugin p : plugins) {
            p.onEnable();
        }
        
        //Disable plugins
        for(Plugin p : plugins) {
            p.onDisable();
        }
    }

}
```

I won't go into much detail here as I think it's pretty self-explanatory. If you have a question, just ask me through the comments.

---

After exporting the previously written as a JAR, add it to the classpath in a new project. Don't forget to create a `plugin.properties` file.

This is an example plugin that is compatible with the `.properties` file specified above:

```
package com.example.plugins;

public class ExamplePlugin extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
}
```

When I export this plugin and put it in the plugins folder I get the following output:
`Hello world!`

### The End

It would be recommended to use JSON or YAML, XML etc. instead of the built-in Java property files. This is the basic structure for plugins. Have fun!